# How to implement the seek steering behavior in Unity3d?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

Following this tutorial: [Understanding Steering Behaviors: Seek](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-seek--gamedev-849), I tried to add seek and steering behavior to my Unity prototype but it's not working this is my script. The cube does not steer it just follows the target.

```
public GameObject target;

    float maxForce = 15;
    float maxSpeed = 30;
    float maxVelocity = 200;
    float mass = 15;

    Vector3 velocity;

    void Start() {
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update() {
        transform.LookAt(target.transform);

        var desiredVelocity = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        desiredVelocity = desiredVelocity.normalized * maxVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

        var steering = desiredVelocity - velocity;
        steering = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(steering, maxForce);
        steering = steering / mass;

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity + steering, maxSpeed);
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

    }
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: If it's correctly following the target, then it sounds like the steering behaviour is performing as advertised. Can you describe what you mean by "does not steer" in more detail?

Comment: The object does not steer towards the target but instead, it just goes straight to the target without any steering behavior.

Comment: You mean that if the object was moving with a particular velocity, then the target moved, the object heads directly to the new target without its path visibly arcing? It sounds like you've tuned the `maxForce` parameter too high for your mass & typical speeds. If it can, this script will complete its turn in a single frame and head directly in the new direction. It's the `maxForce` that limits how much it can change its velocity in a single frame. Have you tried tuning the parameters to achieve your desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks i made some changes to the values it works perfectly now

Answer (score 3):

I had to make some adjustments to the values this works perfectly.

```
   public float Mass = 15;
    public float MaxVelocity = 3;
    public float MaxForce = 15;

    private Vector3 velocity;
    public Transform target;

    private void Start() {
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void Update() {
        var desiredVelocity = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        desiredVelocity = desiredVelocity.normalized * MaxVelocity;

        var steering = desiredVelocity - velocity;
        steering = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(steering, MaxForce);
        steering /= Mass;

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity + steering, MaxVelocity);
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.forward = velocity.normalized;

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, velocity.normalized * 2, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, desiredVelocity.normalized * 2, Color.magenta);

    }
```